# Lauching to MapFragment / Pressing back button from MapFragment results in black screen for long period

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, supportmapfragment

I have implemented Google Maps Android API v2 in my applcation.

Currently I have an Activity which consists of different fragments:

```
public class MyTravelogueActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    int travelogueID;
    String placeID;
    boolean isTravelogue;
    Bundle b;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        String checkStatus = "";

        b = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, getSupportFragmentManager().POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            checkStatus = savedInstanceState.getString("statusCheck");

            b = savedInstanceState.getBundle("bundle");

       } 
        else {
            checkStatus = (String) b.get("status");

        }

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_frag);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        /*
        codes to add Fragment to ft
        */
        ft.commit();
    } 
}
```

So this calls for my MapFragment Class...

```
public class TravelogueSEOPageFragment extends SherlockFragment {

    //............. codes
    public void Map(View view){
        if(hasConnection() == true){
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt("id", travelogueID);
            b.putString("currentlayoutview", currentview);
            FragmentTransaction ft = getSherlockActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            TOnlineMapViewFragment mapfrag = TOnlineMapViewFragment.newInstance(b, place_list);
            ft.replace(R.id.container, mapfrag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why is it that on loading the Google Maps, there is a display of black screen for awhile? When finished viewing the maps, on clicking the back button, the black screen is displayed even longer.

I'm not sure what other codes I should paste to illustrate this problem, so please let me know if I'm lacking any codes to better allow me to ask for a solution to this phenomenon.

Answer (score 0):

This is described by Google as a "known limitation".  See here: [Issue 4639](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4639).  There is an officially proposed workaround but this does not work in all situations.